# C++. Program keeps exiting after input

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem with my code. So my homework asked this:

A mobile phone service provide rhas three different subscription packages for its customers:

Package A: For $39.99 per month 450 minutes are provided. Additional minutes are $0.45 per minute.

Package B: For $59.99 per month 900 minutes are provided. Additional minutes are $0.40 per minute.

Package C: For $69.99 per month unlimited minutes are provided.

Write a program that calculates a customer's monthly bill. It should ask which package the customer has purchased and how many minutes were used. It should then display the total amount due.

*Input validation: Be sure the user only selects package A, B, or C.*

And this is my code for it:

```
/*

1. Set variables (chars, int, etc) for hours and fees.
2. Ask user to select between A, B, or C.
3. Ask user to input time.
Also set a maximum amount of time for each case and setting a maximum amount of time for the     month.
5.Use case switch for options
6.calculate the customers bill for the month apprioprately.

*/


#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const double packageA = 39.99;//set variables for all three. They don't change. 
const double packageB = 59.99;
const double packageC = 69.99;
char choices = ' '; // use "char" for the packages(choices)
int time = 0; // set time as integer. Since some may be decimals, I use double. 
double letter = 0.0; //use "letter" for whatever letter they choose. 
cout << "Read choices below and select choice."<<endl;
cout << "A.$39.99 per month gets 450 minutes. Additional minutes are $0.45 per minute." << endl;
cout << "B.$59.99 per month gets 900 minutes. Additional minutes are $0.40 per minute." << endl;
cout << "C.$69.99 per month gets you unlimited access" << endl;


cout << "Select A, B, or C" << endl;
cin >> letter;

if (choices == 'A' || choices == 'B' || choices == 'C')//using switch case
{

    cout << "Enter minutes:" << endl;//ask user to input time
    cin >> time;


    if (time>0 && time<43829)// 43829 is the max amount of minutes in a month. 0 is the least they person can have. If it fits the requirements, then it can continue. 

    {

        switch (choices)
        {
        case 'A':
            if (time<450)
                letter = packageA;// if the time is less than required. Then no extra charge. 
            else
                letter = ((time - 450)*0.45) + packageA;// if it exceeds maximum minutes and 45 cents is charged. Same for all cases below except its respective amount is charged. 
            break;
        case 'B':
            if (time<900)
                letter = packageB;
            else
                letter = ((time - 900)*.40) + packageB;
            break;
        case 'C':
            letter = packageC;// if not, then package C and no equation since time is unlimited. It is a one time fee for all time used. 
            break;


        default: cout << "Total amount due is: $" << letter << endl; // give total amount charged based on information entered. 
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

}
```

My problem is when I run it, it closes after I select a letter. If I was to select A, it closes automatically. I get this message after it closes:

'ConsoleApplication7.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Prince\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication7\Debug\ConsoleApplication7.exe'. Symbols loaded.

'ConsoleApplication7.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'ConsoleApplication7.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'ConsoleApplication7.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'ConsoleApplication7.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Bitdefender\Bitdefender 2015\active virus control\Avc3_00259_008\avcuf32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'ConsoleApplication7.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'ConsoleApplication7.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

The program '[3476] ConsoleApplication7.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Don't you want `cin >> choices` ?

Comment: Sounds like it's time for you to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: The error messages suggests your antivirus might be interfering also, try turning it off

Comment: Those messages are Visual Studio Loading Debug Symbols. It's a good thing, if your code hit a serious error, it could track it to a line.

Comment: But I don't get it. What are the down votes for, because I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "Select A, B, or C" << endl;
cin >> letter  // (*);
```

The problem is on line marked by `(*)`: you are trying to enter a string data while letter is of type double. Either change letter to string or char. and don't set it to 0.0 or anything else. Just try something like this:

```
String letter;
```

or

```
char letter;
```

I also noticed that you have `char choice = '';` so you can use `cin >> choice` instead of `cin >> letter;`.

Comment: Now it closes after I enter the minutes. but same errors.

Comment: @user2221218 ok so when you created the variable time, in the comments you say that that time might have decimals so you are declaring it as double but in reality you are really not. look at your code it says int time = 0; thats not double. you should be declaring it like this : double time; try this and let me know what happens

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there's a couple of problems in the code - some program-killers, and some logical and reading improvements. We'll start with the program-killers

1. You're asking the person to enter a letter, but attempting to store it in a double format (letter). You'd be better of storing it into a string, then converting it to a character later on (for program compatibility), or simply to request a character to begin with.

> char choices= 'A'; // Though you'd be better calling it something like "package", for readability later on

Then, when you ask for their input, have the line be:

```
cout << "Select A, B, or C" << endl;
cin >> choices;
```

The advantage of using a character is that you can use it in the switch statement below as well (as you are).

2. The next issue is that you're using a default case in the switch incorrectly. The default case is what happens when the switch statement doesn't match any of the other selections (ie, if they enter something other than 'A', 'B', or 'C'. To have it work correctly, you'd want your program to output the total amount after the switch statement.

> ```
> switch (choices) 
> { 
> case 'A': 
>     // do something
>     break; 
> case 'B': 
>     // do something 
>     break; 
> case 'C': 
>     // do something 
>     break;
> }; 
> cout << "Total amount due is: $" << letter << endl;
> ```

3. Validation checks. Currently, you have several validation checks, including valid amount of minutes, should they be charged for extra time, etc. Your validation of the time should be:

   if (time >=0 && time < 43829)

Mainly because 0 is a valid number of minutes to have used. Also, months with 31 days have 44640 minutes. 30 days = 43200 minutes. Where did 43829 come from?
Also, in your switch statement, you check

```
if(time < 450)
```

This should be changed to:

```
if (time <= 450)
```

As 450 minutes are included in the plan. (This should be changed for the 900 minute plan as well).

Improvements include:

- If they choose option C, logically, they shouldn't have to enter their minutes - they have unlimited, and no number they enter will affect their amount (though I can understand the inclusion of it for simplicity and / or assignment requirement).
- Changing some names for readability, such as change letter to "cost / total"
- Add some sort of "You entered a non-accepted plan letter" message when they don't enter A, B, or C.